# How do mothers handle acid from embryo bone mineralization?

Tags: zoology, embryology

This is a relatively trivial question, but, I have not seen it discussed much. It could be one factor in the "acidosis of pregnancy" (JAMA, 1929). Are the compensatory mechanisms measurable, by dietary phosphate requirements increase by 3 mmol (40% more than adult average of 7.4 mmol) or something similar?

A human fetus  acquires 30 gram of calcium during pregnancy (Kovacs, 2014). The molecular weight of calcium is 40 gram per mole, 30 gram is 30/40 = 0.75 moles. Bone mineralization releases hydrogen ions since bone mineral requires hydroxide ions (Bonucci, 1992). Calcium and hydroxide ions have a 5:1 ratio in bone mineral, bone mineralization during embryogenesis releases 0.75/5 = 0.15 moles of hydrogen ions, 150 mmol.

80% of this H+ is generated during the third trimester of gestation (Kovacs, 2014), with up to 1.5 mmol per day (300 mg calcium/day, see Kovacs, 2014) between weeks 35 and 38. When 1.5 mmol H+ is distrubuted on an average 70 kg body, with 60% water, 70 kg * 60% = 42 kg = 42 L of water, the molarity is 1.5 mmol/42 L = 0.035 mmol/L. This is equal to -log10(0.035 mmol) = pH 4.45.

**References**

THE ACIDOSIS OF PREGNANCY. (1929). Journal of the American Medical Association, 92(25), 2104. https://doi.org/10.1001/jama.1929.02700510034014

Kovacs, C. S. (2014). Bone Development and Mineral Homeostasis in the Fetus and Neonate: Roles of the Calciotropic and Phosphotropic Hormones. Physiological Reviews, 94(4), 1143–1218. https://doi.org/10.1152/physrev.00014.2014

Bonucci, E. (1992). V. Regulation of hydroxyapatite formation. In Calcification in Biological Systems (p. 134). Boca Raton: CRC Press.

Comment: 1.5 mmol/d is nothing. By some estimates, a typical adult produces non-volatile acid at 70 mmol/d even in the non-pregnant state. (This includes H+ as a by-product of metabolism, from the diet, and due to intestinal losses of bicarbonate.) How this 70 mmol/d is handled makes for interesting reading. I believe the same processes also handle the excess H+ produced by the foetus in pregnancy.